# roxygen2 "Error: titlerequires a value"

Tags: r, roxygen, roxygen2

I'm receiving an error from `roxygenize()` that I can't understand. I have a package of my miscellaneous functions in which the .Rd files are generated via roxygen.

The error is `Error: titlerequires a value`, which suggests that there is no `@title` tag. However there is an `@title` tag in the `kmmisc-package.R` file, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

`kmmisc-package.R` contains:

```
##' Miscellaneous Functions
##' 
##' \tabular{ll}{
##' Package: \tab kmmisc\cr
##' Type: \tab Package\cr
##' Version: \tab 0.1-2\cr
##' Date: \tab 2011-10-06\cr    
##' License: \tab GPL-2\cr
##' LazyLoad: \tab yes\cr
##' LazyData: \tab yes\cr
##' }
##' 
##' @author Me \email{my@@email}
##' 
##' Maintainer: Me \email{my@@email}
##'
##' @name kmmisc-package
##' @docType package
##' @title KM Misc
##' @keywords package
##' 
NULL
```

I'm using R 2.13.2 with roxygen2 2.1 just reinstalled from CRAN. The complete `sessionInfo()` is in the gist at https://gist.github.com/1268056

## Edit

At @andrie's suggestion, I now have

```
#' Miscellaneous Functions
#' 
#' \tabular{ll}{
#' Package: \tab kmmisc\cr
#' Type: \tab Package\cr
#' Version: \tab 0.1-2\cr
#' Date: \tab 2011-09-14\cr    
#' License: \tab GPL-2\cr
#' LazyLoad: \tab yes\cr
#' LazyData: \tab yes\cr
#' }
#' 
#' @author Me \email{my@@email}
#' 
#' Maintainer: Me \email{my@@email}
#' @name package-kmmisc
#' @docType package
#' @title KM Misc
#' @keywords package
#' @aliases kmmisc package-kmmisc
#'
#' 
NULL
```

which is still generating the same error.

Comment: I just spotted that `maintainer` doesn't have an `@`.  Does this make a difference?

Comment: I don't think so. I might be overlooking something, but, as far as I can tell, I have the same basic structure as the roxygen docs: https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/blob/master/R/roxygen.R I don't have examples or seealso, but I can't think that matters.

Comment: One more suggestion: upgrade to `roxygen2`.  I found this to be more a bit more forgiving and helpful in its hints when it encounters errors in the roxygen lines.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is with roxygen2 (ver. 2.1).

Comment: Sorry, I'm running out of suggestions.  Except maybe this: Delete all .rd files.  Then comment out all roxygen lines.  Then uncomment them function by function and run roxygenize().  In that way you can systematically eliminate potential issues.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Actually usually this runs as a shell script, the first step of which is deleting all the .Rd files. I'll see if I can reduce it down to the minimum possible set that compiles.

Comment: File a bug at https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues.  I haven't had much time to work on roxygen2 lately, but that way it won't get lost

Comment: I doubt if the error really came from this file. This is not the only file under the `R` directory, right? Have you checked other R scripts to make sure there are no empty `@title` tags or empty first lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not replicate the error form the your first code...
Are you receiving same error message from `roxygenize()` to the following simple example?

```
#' A test function
#'
#' Description
#'
#' Details
#'
#' @param x numeric number
f1 <- function(x) {
  x
}
```

---

*An additional information*:

The code by @Andrie, `#' @aliases kmmisc package-kmmisc`, has a [@aliases problem](http://www.mail-archive.com/roxygen-devel@lists.r-forge.r-project.org/msg00091.html).
In roxygen2 2.1, `#' @aliases a-b`, which has a hyphen, generates the Rd quoted tag `\alias{"a-b"}`.
In this case the code has no problem, but in other case requires some attention.
Of course, if you need quoted tags, you add `#' @aliases a-b`.

So I think that it's better to replace `#' @aliases kmmisc package-kmmisc` with `#' @aliases kmmisc` in this case:

```
#' Miscellaneous Functions
#'
#' \tabular{ll}{
#' Package: \tab kmmisc\cr
#' Type: \tab Package\cr
#' Version: \tab 0.1-2\cr
#' Date: \tab 2011-09-14\cr
#' License: \tab GPL-2\cr
#' LazyLoad: \tab yes\cr
#' LazyData: \tab yes\cr
#' }
#'
#' @author Me \email{my@@email}
#'
#' Maintainer: Me \email{my@@email}
#' @name package-kmmisc
#' @aliases kmmisc
#' @docType package
#' @title KM Misc
#' @keywords package
NULL
```

Comment: This is what I wished to fix: https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/pull/29 But here I do not see any reason why the title was broken due to incorrect aliases.

Comment: Sorry for the digression.  I revised my post.  I'm looking forward to fix: #29.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Uncomment your roxygen statements.  (This might be a SO artefact, but each roxygen line should start with `# '`, i.e. a single `#`)
- Make the following changes to the documentation

```
    #' @name package-kmmisc
    #' @aliases kmmisc package-kmmisc
```

In other words:

- Change the value of `@name`
- Add an alias called `kmmisc`

---

These are the only differences between your example and my own package documentation.

Comment: I still get the same error with these edits (see edit above). Generally though, is ## ' really a problem? That's what ESS does by default (at least I think I have the default settings).

Comment: If `##` works for you, that's great and I've learnt something.  I use Eclipse and the Roxygen code highlighting only works with a single `#`

Comment: I can confirm `##'` certainly works. As Kevin said, this is the default prefix in Emacs. I do not see any obvious problems in the code, and actually I can run roxygen2 with it without any errors (R 2.13.2 under Ubuntu).